# Is there a function in Windows API similar to ftruncate on POSIX?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I am using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from Windows API to open a file. Now this function returns a `HANDLE` object on which we further use Read or Write or any of the filing operations.

I have found [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which talks about truncating files but it has no parameter for size of file. Finally, [_chsize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk925tyb.aspx) function doesn't accept a `HANDLE` object. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

Use `SetFilePointer` or `SetFilePointerEx`to set the current position to the size you want, then call `SetEndOfFile`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! [`_chsize_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chsize-s?view=msvc-170) in io.h. Works just like `ftruncate()`, with the same parameters and all. Just `#define ftruncate _chsize_s`. (Use `_chsize_s()` with a 64-bit offset parameter, as opposed to `_chsize()` which has a 32-bit offset parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

`SetEndOfFile` will use the current file pointer location within the file to truncate it at that point.  If you want a specific size, you can use [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to move the pointer to the desired location.